# (Neopixels) How to keep the pixels of the same colour despite increasing brightness?

Tags: arduino-uno, neopixel

I've been doing a fade function for the NeoPixels. However, the moment I have maximum brightness for the pixels, *I noticed there 2 colours even though in my function I have only specified one colour*.

Some strips are one colour and the others are another colour. I
specified the colour to be blue for the strips however many strips are blue and the strips nearer the end are green (but closer to a blue-green colour).

Is there any way to keep the colour even when the brightness changes? I've read somewhere online a different colour is seen with different brightness levels i.e. `setPixelColor(brightness, r,g,b)`.

I've also tried FastLED library and followed documentation. However, the lights are not doing what it has said in the codes, I've tried `leds[i].fadeLightBy(200)` and it has given me no result.

My code for the fade function (edited from http://moving-rainbow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/fade-in-and-out/):

```cpp
void fade(uint32_t color) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    for (int q = 0; q < strip.numPixels(); q++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(q, Wheel((color) & 255));
    }
    strip.setBrightness(i);
    strip.show();
  }

  //decreasing brightness
  for (int l = 255; l > 255; l--) {
    for (int p = 0; p < strip.numPixels(); p++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(p, Wheel((color) & 255));
    }
    strip.setBrightness(l);
    strip.show();
  }
}
```

The method "Wheel" is from the Arduino Neopixel strandtest example.

```cpp
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if (WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if (WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
}
```

Any advice on how I should go about doing it?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "2 colours". Do you mean that some of the LEDs on the strip are one color and other LEDs are a different color? If so, is there a particular pattern to which LEDs are which color? How different are the colors?

Comment: @per1234  I've edited the question to make it easier to understand. Sorry about that. Yes, the strips nearer the end are a different colour to the one I specified i.e. at the end it's more green than blue.

Answer (score 1):

I have some simple NeoPixel fading going on in this example sketch:

```
/*
 * 
 * NeoPixels demo - fades colours (in array) up and down
 * 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NeoPixels_SPI.h>

const unsigned int PIXELS = 8; // Number of pixels in the string

void setup()
  {
  ledsetup();
  } // end of setup

float patterns [] [3] = {
  { 1, 0, 0 },  // red
  { 0, 1, 0 },  // green
  { 0, 0, 1 },  // blue
  { 1, 1, 0 },  // yellow
  { 1, 0, 1 },  // magenta
  { 0, 1, 1 },  // cyan
  { 1, 1, 1 },  // white
  { 160.0 / 256, 82.0 / 256, 45.0 / 256 },  // sienna
  { 46.0 / 256, 139.0 / 256, 87.0 / 256 },  // sea green

};

// number of items in an array
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

void loop() 
  {

  for (byte i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE (patterns); i++) 
    {
    // fade up
    for (byte m = 0; m < 100; m++)
      {
      showColor (PIXELS, patterns [i] [0] * m, patterns [i] [1] * m, patterns [i] [2] * m);
      delay (10);
      } // end of for

    // fade down
    for (byte m = 100; m > 0; m--)
      {
      showColor (PIXELS, patterns [i] [0] * m, patterns [i] [1] * m, patterns [i] [2] * m);
      delay (10);
      } // end of for
    } // end of for each array item

  } // end of loop
```

This is using the simple [NeoPixel library](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=13357) that I wrote using the SPI hardware. The library with the exact code above is [available here](https://github.com/nickgammon/NeoPixels_SPI).

Basically the fading is done by multiplying the floating-point values for the R/G/B values by a constant from 0 to 100 (you could make it 0 to 255).

Since the colours themselves are expressed in the range 0 .. 1 then the result of the multiplication would be 0 to 255. To my naked eye the colours seem true at all brightnesses.

To use the library on your Uno just connect +5V, Gnd, and the data pin is MOSI (D11 on the Uno).