# How do i fade a colorwipe from off to on in 1 color?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

So I want to make the same effect as a colorwipe (like going around in a circle turning leds on till they all turn on) except that instead of going from off to 100% brightness immediately I need it to look more natural by making it fade from off to on gradually to a single color and the LEDS should stay on after the fade on is complete. This is my current code and i cant figure out how to make it fade. everything ive found on google is massively complex to do a simple thing. is it really that complex to accomplish this?

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 6
#define NUM_LEDS 24
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRBW + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.setBrightness(2);
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 255, 255, 255), 70); //white

}

// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want them to glow up one after the other or have the next one to start glowing while the previous one hasn't yet reached full brightness?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "wait" variable is not actually used in your colorwipe function.

The colorwipe function seems to turn them all on in succession. The only thing you need to do is add fading to it.

```
for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    for(uint8_t brightness=0; brightness<maxBrightness; brightness++){
       strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(brightness, brightness, brightness, brightness );
       strip.show();
       delay(wait);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/48855/10794).

Code from that answer:

```
/*
 * 
 * NeoPixels demo - fades colours (in array) up and down
 * 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NeoPixels_SPI.h>

const unsigned int PIXELS = 8; // Number of pixels in the string

void setup()
  {
  ledsetup();
  } // end of setup

float patterns [] [3] = {
  { 1, 0, 0 },  // red
  { 0, 1, 0 },  // green
  { 0, 0, 1 },  // blue
  { 1, 1, 0 },  // yellow
  { 1, 0, 1 },  // magenta
  { 0, 1, 1 },  // cyan
  { 1, 1, 1 },  // white
  { 160.0 / 256, 82.0 / 256, 45.0 / 256 },  // sienna
  { 46.0 / 256, 139.0 / 256, 87.0 / 256 },  // sea green

};

// number of items in an array
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

void loop() 
  {

  for (byte i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE (patterns); i++) 
    {
    // fade up
    for (byte m = 0; m < 100; m++)
      {
      showColor (PIXELS, patterns [i] [0] * m, patterns [i] [1] * m, patterns [i] [2] * m);
      delay (10);
      } // end of for

    // fade down
    for (byte m = 100; m > 0; m--)
      {
      showColor (PIXELS, patterns [i] [0] * m, patterns [i] [1] * m, patterns [i] [2] * m);
      delay (10);
      } // end of for
    } // end of for each array item

  } // end of loop
```

Comment: thanks! so i just copy and paste this whole thing in and it will work? or do i add it to my existing code? im very new to this.

Comment: Also just to clarify i need it to go around in a circle and fill up the neopixel circle. (think like a magic circle).

Comment: To use that exact code you need [my library](https://github.com/nickgammon/NeoPixels_SPI). Also the NeoPixels have to have their data pin connected to D11 (digital pin 11) on the Uno.

Comment: That particular code fades in the colours shown (red, green, blue etc.) in sequence.

Comment: ah i just need white.

Comment: ok so @nick gammon your program works but all it does it fade. the lights dont move around the circle at all. i dont know how to make them move in a circle.